# Vertex Covers whose vertex induced subgraph has an even number of edges and no isolated vertices

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, counting-complexity

Let $G$ be a graph, and let $C_{E,0}$ be the number of those vertex covers of $G$ satisfying both the following properties:

- Their corresponding vertex induced subgraph has an even number of edges.
- Their corresponding vertex induced subgraph has no isolated vertices.

> **Questions**
>
> 1. Did anyone already study the problem of computing $C_{E,0}$? What is known about it?
> 2. More importantly, which is the computational complexity of computing $C_{E,0}\ mod\ 2$?